# unoconv not working on ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: shell, ubuntu-12.04, libreoffice, ubuntu-server

I am using `unoconv` to convert different file formats to pdf. It is working well on my local machine for all formats. But on my ubuntu 12.04 server `unoconv` is failing for some formats such as xls, ppt, pptx etc. However it is working fine for doc files. It shows the following error for the ppt conversion.

```
$unoconv -f pdf Googling.ppt 
unoconv: UnoException during conversion in <class '__main__.com.sun.star.lang.IllegalArgumentException'>: Unsupported URL <file:///home/pythonuser/almamapper/media/library/files/c1cb92e62ce54b29a017a6e8eaa23c/Googling.ppt>: ""
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/unoconv", line 790, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/bin/unoconv", line 769, in main
convertor.convert(inputfn)
File "/usr/bin/unoconv", line 679, in convert
error("ERROR: The provided document cannot be converted to the desired format. (code: %s)" % e.ErrCode)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uno.py", line 337, in _uno_struct__getattr__
return __builtin__.getattr(self.__dict__["value"],name)
AttributeError: ErrCode
```

I know I have to install openoffice-headless version on my server. But from this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194352/install-openoffice-for-headless-use) I understand that Ubuntu switched to libreoffice instead of openoffice quite a while ago. So I installed libreoffice by the following command.

`apt-get install libreoffice-core libreoffice-writer libreoffice-calc`

But still am getting the same error. Am I missing something to install? Do anyone have any thoughts on this issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I fixed the above issue by installing latest version of `unoconv`. I tried updating libreoffice and installing complete version, neither helped.

I was using `unoconv 0.3`, and the latest available version is 0.6. So I installed the latest one and it solved the issue.

Here is the steps i followed:

1. `apt-get remove --purge unoconv` (remove the old unoconv first)
2. `git clone https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv`
   (download latest version of unoconv from github.)
3. now cd to unoconv directory and do `sudo make install`

Note: pls do git clone, dont download the tar file. In my case the installation failed when I downloaded the tar.

Comment: I found this excellent blog (https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/Installing_unoconv) for installing and setting up `unoconv`.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same general problem after doing `apt-get install unoconv`, an additional `apt-get install libreoffice` fixed it. Probably your limited install of only some libreoffice components is the reason it only works for some formats. Certainly I would expect it to need `libreoffice-impress` for ppt conversion?

Comment: I tried that too. And at the end I resolved it by installing latest version of `unoconv`. Answer given below. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I had the issue for doc conversion (`-f doc`) with `unoconv`. And I could indeed solve the issue after a `apt-get install libreoffice-writer`, thanks @HermanHiddema. But I also needed to kill the running soffice process `killall soffice.bin` otherwise it didn't work.

Comment: @AndreMiras this is also the case when trying to run this on an Ubuntu Desktop. I develop against a 12.04 desktop environment and deploy against a 12.04 server. If you have a document open in LibreOffice and you try to convert a document at the command line, the conversion will silently fail.

Comment: @AndreMiras, Thanks for saving the day by mentioning ````killall soffice.bin````. I was wondering why I wasn't getting the result.